# onKeyDown / Up Listener in JS class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an easy game on JS. For now i have a "Hero" class that have 3 functions: spawn hero, move and stop hero. This class -

```
 export default class Hero {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.position = 120;
    this.isRunning = false;
  }

 spawn = () => {
   //....here some spawn logic

   document.addEventListener("keydown", this.move);
   document.addEventListener("keyup", this.stop);
 }

 move = (e) => {
   let { isRunning, position } = this;

   //... here i have a logic that change Hero "position" and "isRunning" flag. 
   //... For exapmle -

   position += 10;
   isRunning = true;
 }

 stop = () => {
   isRunning = true;
 }
}
```

> My problem is then i click on some keyboard key my variables **isRunning and position** change only inside **move or stop functions** but not global, i.e **isRunning and position** vars always = false and 120 respectively.
>
> My question is why this happen and how i can change this vars globally? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `this` keyword. As these variables are properties of your object. So `this.position += 10`.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, it works!!! At first I thought it was the same thing, but only now I understood the essence)